# Something Wrong with my angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am building simple nodejs restful api with angular. The server side (which is restful express) working with no issues I can get post and delete or put json inputs with no problems but once it get to the front end which by using angular I face an issue. I cant get the data from the server I am not sure why!!!

This is the server Side

appJs

```
// Tools to be used in the web development
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//To connect it to the web front-end
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
//To read data from forms
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Models to be used
Genre = require('./models/genre.js');
Book = require('./models/book.js');


// Database Connection
let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.openUri('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

conn.on('error', err => console.error('mongodb connection error', 
err));
conn.on('connected', () => console.info(`Connected to mongodb`));
conn.on('disconnected', () => console.info('Disconnected from 
mongodb'));


// Routing to specific pages:

// Get requests
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/genres', function(req , res){
Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genres);
})
});

app.get('/api/books', function(req , res){
Book.getBooks(function(err, books){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(books);
})
});

app.get('/api/books/:_id', function(req , res){
Book.getBookById(req.params._id, function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});

//Post Requests
app.post('/api/genres', function(req , res){
var genre = req.body;
Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
})
});


app.post('/api/books', function(req , res){
var book = req.body;
Book.addBook(book, function(err, book){
  if(err){
     throw err;
  }
  res.json(book);
})
});

//Put requests
app.put('/api/genres/:_id', function(req , res){
var id = req.params._id;
var genre = req.body;
Genre.updateGenre(id, genre,{}, function(err, genre){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
})
});

app.put('/api/books/:_id', function(req , res){
var id = req.params._id;
var book = req.body;
Book.updateBook(id, book,{}, function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});

//Delete Requests
app.delete('/api/genres/:_id', function(req , res){
var id = req.params._id;
Genre.deleteGenre(id, function(err, genre){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
})
});

app.delete('/api/books/:_id', function(req , res){
var id = req.params._id;
Book.deleteBook(id, function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});





//Specify the listening port
app.listen(3000);
//Display the url on the termianl
console.log('Server Running On http://localhost:3000');
```

And this is from the front end angularJs

app.Js this for the routing

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/books.html'
})
.when('/books',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/books.hrml'
})
.when('/books/details/:id',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/book_details.html'
})
.when('/books/add', {
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/add_book.html'
})
.when('/books/edit/:id', {
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/edit_book.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
})
});
```

booksJs from the front end angularJs to get the information from the server: Hint: I think the problem from this file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 
'$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
console.log('Books Controller loaded')


$scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response){
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
}
}]);
```

and this the panel where it display the data from the bookJs and present it

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBooks">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Latest Books</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class "row">
    <div ng-repeat="book in books">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{book.title}}
                <p>{{book.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="{{book.image_url}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this the main index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>BookStore</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BookStore</a>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/books/add">Add Book</a>
      </li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class = "row">
      <div class ="col-md-12">

        <div ng-view></div>

      </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->





    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js">
</script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/books.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/genres.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

the information I get once I process Get /api/books using postman which prove the issue not from the backend:

[image: PostMan]

and once I run using the fronend:

[image: ServerWithFrontRunning]

WHich appear that the panel from books.html works put getting the data from books.js has an issue!! any suggestion?

Comment: Tips and tricks: the browser has developer tools. Hit F12 (Cmd-Alt-I on Mac) to open them. You can put breakpoints in your code to debug it, look for logs and errors in the console, see which requests are being sent and which response you get. You should have at least checked if there was an error, if your controller was instantiated, if getBooks() was being called, and if a request was sent. That would have led you to your mistake.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet this would be handy and useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-init="getBooks"` will not call function (missing parenthesis`()`), avoid using `ng-init`, instead call it from `getBooks` function from `controller`

```
myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 
'$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log('Books Controller loaded')


  $scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response){
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
  }
  function init(){
     $scope.getBooks();
  }
  init();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like to this: `ng-init="getBooks()"`

But it's better use `init` function as @Pankaj Parkar's answer and don't use `ng-init` directive.